# Python Scrapy selecting text from table column

Tags: python, scrapy

```
def parse(self, response):
    for row in response.css('body table:nth-child(5)'):
        yield {
            'name': row.css('tr td:nth-child(2)').extract()
        }
```

I'm trying to specify getting the text in this selector but can't seem to get it working. It gets the full element no problem but I only want the text. If I attach the css selector ::text it only returns empty strings.

Result is 
[
{"name": ["\u00a0\u00a0", "**John Doe** ",  and so on}
]

Comment: What have you tried? Please also include info about what response variable is.

Comment: i edited post there to show an example of the result as well as using the css selector ::text

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide example of `response` variable from which you got your resuilt. Please also see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: figured it out, just realized the text was inside an <a> element

Answer (score 0):

If you use selector `el::text` it will extract only text nodes inside `<el>`, while text inside table's cells can be (and most probably, is) wrapped with some nesting tags like `span`, `p`, etc. To extract all the nested text nodes of `<el>` you can use `el *::text` selector.